# select element validation doesn't working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an Index.html file in which I am giving two options two different values (Yes or No).

Issue:

I want to validate with those values in JS but when I am doing it can't hold the value of that.

What I Have:
Index.html:

```
<select id="sel">
  <option value="yes" >Yes</option>
  <option value="no" >No</option>
</select>
```

Valid.js:

```
var sel=document.getElementById("sel").value;
localStorage.setItem("sel", sel);
```

Calculate.js:

I have to validated here I have connected Confirm.html with form action in Index.html.

In confirm.html I am loading `init()` method of calculate.js

```
var sel = localStorage.getItem("sel");
```

Comment: The `.value` return value of selected option if any option is selected

Comment: When is the Valid.js file being loaded, and are the lines of code in that file contained inside a function or not?

Comment: valid.js file loaded with index,html whenever user select any values yes or no it will store in sel variable then transfer using localstorage to calculate.js

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the code for the validation and calculation are both in different files I would highly recommend checking the order in which you load the scripts in your HTML file, alternatively you could just attach an event listener to the selection tag which would trigger each time the user changes the selection like so;

```
document
  .getElementById('sel')
  .addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    localStorage.setItem("sel", this.value);
  })
```

and then when validating input check whether the "sel" value is present within the localStorage just as you originally planned.

Comment: The important piece of this change is the use of `.value`, rather than the `HTMLSelectElement`. You may wish to emphasize that part.